# Create a new Image with Image Magick in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, imagemagick

I am looking for an example to create a new Image e.g. a jpg file with a rectangle in it with ImageMagick.

I want this because Imagemagick cannot convert a MS Excel file to an image. I am thinking to create a blank image with a rectangle and then name of file in it. Its better then showing a broken image.

I have seen this [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=11747) but its only for PHP.

Assembly of Magick.net : **Magick.NET-AnyCPU**

Comment: Which C# library are you using for ImageMagick?

Comment: I am using Assembly Magick.NET-AnyCPU